# How to create new Custom Login Popup in Dotnetnuke 7?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

> Hi, 
>       My Questions are :
>
> > 1. I just want to create Login Popup in DNN 7 according to my requirements and CSS.
> >        Please suggest way for it .
> > 2. also Which is better way ...to Customize existing Login & Forgot Password Pages or to Create New Pages for these.
> > 3. Is there any Free utility or service to make DNN development Easy
> >          (Searched for Nucleus but could not find helpful info)
> >        Please Suggest and provide useful Links also ..Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

So Stackoverflow is great for 1 question at a time, I will start with #1 and ask you to break it up into other questions for the rest.

1. Does it need to be a popup? If not, try just creating a custom Login page and put the Account Login module on that, then Skin it as you wish.

If it needs to be a custom popup, you can look at the popupskin.ascx file in your SKIN, you can customize the way the popups look by changing your Popup Skin. My free DNN skin has an example of that file https://multifunction.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#popupskin.ascx